# Visual Studio 2017 Code Coverage Reports Partial Coverage on Async Methods

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, code-coverage, xunit

I'm working on a small unit test for a simple asp.net core middleware and trying to work out if it's possible to get 100% coverage on this very basic scenario. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 > "Analyze Code Coverage", xUnit and Moq for completeness. On my async methods (one illustrated below) code analysis is reporting only partial coverage. Is there a way to get these fully covered?

// Sample Middleware

```
internal sealed partial class JsonExceptionMiddleware
{
    private const string DefaultErrorMessage = "A server error occurred.";
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILogger<JsonExceptionMiddleware> _logger;


    public JsonExceptionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _next = next ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(next));
        _logger = loggerFactory?.CreateLogger<JsonExceptionMiddleware>() ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(loggerFactory));

        IncludeExceptionMessage = hostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment();
        IncludeExceptionStackTrace = hostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets whether the <see cref="Exception.StackTrace"/> should be included in the response message.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IncludeExceptionStackTrace { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets whether the <see cref="Exception.Message"/> should be included in the response message.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IncludeExceptionMessage { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Implements the <see cref="RequestDelegate"/> so this class can be used as middleware.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The current <see cref="HttpContext"/>.</param>
    /// <returns>A <see cref="Task"/> that completes when the error message is flush to the HTTP response.</returns>
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (context.Response.HasStarted) throw;

            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            context.Response.ContentType = ApiConstants.Http.JsonContentType;

            ApiError error = BuildError(ex);

            await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(error, new JsonSerializerSettings(){ NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore}));
        }
    }

    private ApiError BuildError(Exception ex)
    {
        string message = DefaultErrorMessage;
        string detail = null;
        string stack = null;

        if (IncludeExceptionMessage)
            detail = ex.Message;

        if (IncludeExceptionStackTrace)
            stack = ex.StackTrace;

        var error = new ApiError(message, detail, stack);
        return error;
    }
}
```

Blue=covered, Yellow=partially covered, Red=not covered

[image]

[image]

// Sample Unit Test

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task SampleUnit()
    {
        // arrange

        var environment = new Mock<IHostingEnvironment>();
        environment
            .SetupGet(x => x.EnvironmentName)
            .Returns(EnvironmentName.Development);

        var response = new Mock<HttpResponse>();
        response
            .Setup(x => x.HasStarted)
            .Returns(true);

        var httpContext = new Mock<HttpContext>();
        httpContext
            .SetupGet(x => x.Response)
            .Returns(response.Object);

        var loggerFactory = new Mock<LoggerFactory>();

        var jsonExceptionMiddleware = new JsonExceptionMiddleware((innerHttpContext) => throw new Exception(SampleExceptionDetail), loggerFactory.Object, environment.Object);

        // act & assert

        await Assert.ThrowsAsync<Exception>(async () => await jsonExceptionMiddleware.Invoke(httpContext.Object).ConfigureAwait(false));
    }
```

Comment: Write more test methods that will cover every execution path

Comment: I have 5 Units that cover all code paths. From what research i've done so far is has to do with the state machines that async methods get compiled down to which contain a path which can never be taken??  I've not found a concrete answer to this MoveNext() issue.

Comment: So even if you do not throw an exception in the request delegate it does not flow through? `new JsonExceptionMiddleware((context) => Task.CompletedTask),...`

Comment: For the other one you just have to make sure an error is thrown and that `context.Response.HasStarted` is true.

Comment: I appreciate it Nkosi -- that was it exactly.  Thanks.

Comment: @Mike I've aggregated my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of the covered code, the test(s) throw on the await and only flows through the catch block.

Allow the `await` to flow to completion by not throwing an exception in the request delegate. Using the sample test provided, you would need to initialize the middleware like this

```
//...

var jsonExceptionMiddleware = new JsonExceptionMiddleware((context) => Task.CompletedTask, 
    loggerFactory.Object, environment.Object);

//...
```

For the other uncovered code, you just have to make sure an error is thrown on the await like it is now, but make sure that `context.Response.HasStarted` is `true`.